# How can I grab the iTunes-defined name for my iPhone/iPod device?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to get the name for an iPhone/iPod device that the user entered in their iTunes.  This is not, I repeat, **not**, necessarily what `[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]` returns (or any of its other methods).

For instance, my iPhone is bound in iTunes to "iPhone 3G de Christophe…", to differentiate it from my wife's and other similar devices. That's the name I'd love to be able to grab. Is it stored anywhere on the device, and if so can I access it somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't have access to a mac to check it out right now, but did you try - http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=129